# Show that there are open sets $P\in U \subset X$ and $Q\in V \subset Y$ and an isomorphism of $U$ to $V$ which sends $P$ to $Q$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a variety. Define local ring of a point. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two varieties. Suppose there are points $P \in X$ and $Q \in Y$ such that the local rings $O_P(X)$ and $O_Q(Y)$ are isomorphic as $k$-algebras. Then show that there are open sets $P\in U \subset X$ and $Q\in V \subset Y$ and an isomorphism of $U$ to $V$ which sends $P$ to $Q$.

Now I have $\phi : O_P(X) \to O_Q(Y)$ which is an isomorphism. Now $O_P(X)=\{f:X \to X$ rational function $|$ $ f$ is regular at $P\}$

So $f=\frac{f_1}{f_2}$ where $f_2(P) \neq 0$ so $\exists ( P \in )U$
 s.t $f_2(u) \neq 0$ $\forall u \in U$ again for $g \in O_Q(X)=\{g:X \to X$ rational function $|$ $ g$ is regular at $Q\}$

So $g=\frac{g_1}{g_2}$ where $g_2(Q) \neq 0$ so $\exists ( Q \in )V$
 s.t $g_2(v) \neq 0$ $\forall v \in V$.

Now construct $\tilde \phi: k(U) \to k(V)$ s.t $f \to \phi(f)$ here the $f$ I am taking belongs to $O_P(X)$ too. Because $f$ is not zero at $P$..

But how to proceed next? Please help.

Comment: It is quite easy to reduce the situation to the following algebraic statement: Let $A \subset B$ be an inclusion of integral domains of finite type over $k$ and $P$ be a prime ideal of $B$. Let $p=P \cap A$. If $A_p=B_P$, then there is some $f \in A \setminus p$, such that $A_f=B_f$. Proving this statement is also easy: Take generators of $B$, write them down as elements in $A_p$ and take $f$ to be the product of all denominators occuring. This makes sure that $B \subset A_f$ holds, which clearly implies $A_f=B_f$.